# Ionic slides - How do you change background smoothly?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, slider, pager

I am using [Ionic Slides](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#slides) in my app.  I wish to gradually change the background colour as I move from the first slide to the second one from white to blue.  I am able to change them abruptly, but how can I make it look like it changes smoothly?

A lot of native apps (e.g. [Buffer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.buffer.android)) do that in their introductory slides.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about adding css animations

Comment: Where should I add CSS animations? I tried to add it to the <ion-slide> tags of individual classes but they took effect only before/after the transition started/ended.  I want the animation to effect during the transition.  Adding animation to the parent <ion-slides> tag doesn't do anything, it seems.

Comment: refer this http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-animate-your-ionic-app-with-animate-css-and-nganimate/ and https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-animations-with-css-in-ionic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there are many ways in which you can do a smooth transition one of which is 
CSS3 animation 
read here 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

or you can use angularjs animation 
read here 
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_animations.asp

Comment: I tried adding that to a my <ion-slide> tags of all slides, but that didn't give the expected result since it worked only after/before slide change. I also tried adding it to the parent <ion-slides> tag, but that doesn't show any effect at all. I guess my question is - where should I be adding this CSS with reference to ion-slides?

Comment: you need to add it the tag for each slide